# Visual studio 2017 community not finding reference properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-assembly

I cloned a project on github and while trying to compile, it gives me missing assembly reference error but the said assembly is within the project and seems to be just fine.

> Error  CS0012  The type 'ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.   UndertaleModTool Converters\RectConverter.cs    16

ValueType is within the dependency ValueTuple.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FORhq.png)

Tried re-installing, updating and setting in the csproj file but i wanted to find a clean solution for this problem; other people seem to be able to compile the project just fine.

Any ideas on how to solve this kind of issue?

link of the project on github for reference https://github.com/krzys-h/UndertaleModTool

Comment: Adding a reference is something you have to do explicitly. This is not a mater of mere code copy&paste. The exact way to reference assemblies varries by IDE/Compiler/Project format.

Comment: Im adding the reference via Nuget package, and as far as i know it should work out of the box, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a Visual studio 2017 community bug, installing vs community 2019 fixes the issue entirely without having to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Download clean project from github

Then try restoring nuget packages for solution demonstrated in screenshot

I've solved the issue in this way. Mine is running property with 3 warnings

[image]

Comment: In that case you can download my working copy from Mediafire http://www.mediafire.com/file/x1njyeanx2tka0s/UndertaleModTool-master.rar/file